# How to create and call elements from this type of list?

Tags: java, android, listview, data-structures

I'm really new to the android world, at the moment I am using sketchware to simplify the process and using custom code when needed.

All tips are welcomed, and also if you have relevant information with sources where I can read from that would be great!

So what I want to do is to make a simple app where there is a texteditor, a textview and a button. That's no problem. But I am stuck as I want to make a list or datastructure that will hold all the postcodes in Norway, with the areas they belong to. So as I input 0653 in the text editor and press the button it will put "Oslo" in the textview. for 7500 "Trondheim" etc.

I cant really put any code here, but what I tried now was 
insert key Oslo value 0653 at 1 in map postnr
if that makes any sense. with this way I would have to add 9999 codes though, which will take very long time to do, not to mention the loading time on the creation.

Answer (score -1):

Well.. As I can understand , you want to put the data into a List of map and then traverse the list wherever it is required. Right??
Now the question is how you can going to insert data into that list.
If u have your data(postalCode and place) in an excel sheet then you can write a java code which reads the file and insert into your list of map.
Here is a code which reads an xlsx file having key value as follows-

OSLO    6053

BOSTON  1841

```
package com.vibbs.demo;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.poi.EncryptedDocumentException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReadDemo {

public static void readXLSFile(Map<String, String> mapByPostCode , Map<String, String> mapByPostValue) throws IOException, EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException
{
    InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("/pathtoFile/postalDemo.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
    Sheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> rows = worksheet.rowIterator();

    Cell postalCodeCell = null;
    Cell postalValueCell = null;
    while(rows.hasNext()) {
        Row row = (Row) rows.next();
        postalValueCell  = row.getCell(0);
        postalCodeCell = row.getCell(1);

        postalValueCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        postalCodeCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

        String postalValue = postalValueCell.getStringCellValue();
        String postalCode = postalCodeCell.getStringCellValue();
        mapByPostCode.put(postalCode, postalValue);
        mapByPostValue.put(postalValue, postalCode);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException {
    //1841 BOSTON , 6053
    Map<String, String> mapByPostCode = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> mapByPostValue = new HashMap<String, String>();

    ExcelReadDemo.readXLSFile(mapByPostCode , mapByPostValue);

    System.out.println(mapByPostCode.get("1841")); // If u provide postcode it will give you place
    System.out.println(mapByPostValue.get("BOSTON")); // If u provide place it will give you postCode
}
}
```

Comment: This seems like what I am after, yes! I could create an excel file that has one column of postal codes with a parallel column of places. Then would it be possible to call the place corresponding to the added postal code? like 0653, it finds 0653 in the excel and then returns Oslo which is in the box next to it? Where can I read more about this?